# Факторизация: разложить натуральное число на простые множители

Tags: php, математика, факторизация

Как разложить натуральное число на простые множители, используя `PHP`?
На данный момент имеется такой код:

```
function factors($n = 0, $array = FALSE) {

    $pf = array();  
    for ($i = 2; $i <= $n / $i; $i++) { 
        while ($n % $i == 0) {
            $pf[] = $i;
            $n = $n / $i;
        }       
    }

    if ($n > 1) $pf[] = $n; 
    return ($array === TRUE) ? $pf : implode(' * ', $pf);
}
```

Можно ли сделать лучше?

Comment: php неподходящий для этого язык.

Comment: Насчёт «быстрее всего» вам придётся хорошо разобраться в [теории чисел](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB).

Comment: Вот вам обзорная статья: http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~yuvalf/Factorization.pdf

Comment: Интересно, а зачем это вообще нужно, да еще кроссплатформенно?

--

Просто, кроме криптоанализа ничего в голову не приходит, но ПХП и крипто????

Comment: может человек узнал, сколько денег дают за факторизацию больших чисел и решил "спрошу на форуме, напишу прогу, разложу по серверам и заработаю".

Comment: На самом деле всё гораздо скучнее - мне просто нужен скрипт на сайт по элементарной математике :)

Comment: Элементарной математикой по этой теме будет только алгоритм тривиального деления. Хорошие результаты дает метод ро-Полларда, он достаточно прост для реализации

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmp-nextprime.php может быть пригодится

Comment: Пройдитесь по сайтам криптографии. Факторизация чисел там часто применяется. В универе помню делал в рамках дисциплины.

Answer (score 2):

Если код запускается под линуксом, то можно вызвать консольную утилиту factor, которая присутствует в многих дистрибутивах. Она работает достаточно быстро и использует [алгоритм Полларда](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A1-%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B0). Статья в википедии имеет много теории и схематический код, который, я думаю, можно будет легко портировать на php.

Comment: Спасибо, не знал про эту утилиту, хотя использую Дебиан. Но мою проблему она не решает - код должен быть кроссплатформенным.

Comment: вообще то от нее есть [исходики](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=coreutils.git;a=blob;f=src/factor.c;h=257a7ed90e1147a580d4ea8ca13da0b98be3562a;hb=HEAD). Она является частью [core utils](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/).

Но вот перевести на php наверно будет сложно. Но если начнете с википедии, то по ссылке, которую я в ответе привел, можно будет найти немножко кода.